# How to cite more than one equation in align environment

Tags: math-mode

I have this

```
\begin{align} \label{components-endomorphism-curvature}
       \tilde{R}_{ABCD} = R_{ABCD},\\
       \tilde{R}_{0ABC} = 0,\\
       \tilde{R}_{0A0B} = e^{2f} \left( \overline{\nabla}_A \overline{\nabla}_B f + \overline{\nabla}_A f \overline{\nabla}_B f \right).
\end{align}
```

which gives

[image]

I would like to cite (2.7) and (2.9) specifically, but only (2.7) appears when I use the command `\ref{components-endomorphism-curvature}`. How can I cite (2.7) and (2.9)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need a `\label` for each line you want to cite. B.t.w., do you really want to align equations  at the end of each line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code you showed, in fact, only the first of the three equations is labeled. You need to add a label for each of the equations that you want to reference.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align} 
    \label{components-endomorphism-curvature-1}
       \tilde{R}_{ABCD} = R_{ABCD}, \\
       \tilde{R}_{0ABC} = 0, \\
    \label{components-endomorphism-curvature-3}
       \tilde{R}_{0A0B} = e^{2f} \left( \overline{\nabla}_A \overline{\nabla}_B f + \overline{\nabla}_A f \overline{\nabla}_B f \right).
\end{align}
Here are references to \eqref{components-endomorphism-curvature-1} and \eqref{components-endomorphism-curvature-3}. 
\end{document}
```

[image]